# Cropping and resizing images on the fly with node.js

Tags: image-processing, node.js, amazon-s3

I run a node.js server on Amazon EC2. I am getting a huge csv file with data containing links to product images on a remote host. I want to crop and store the images in different sizes on Amazon S3.

How could this be done, preferably just with streams, without saving anything to disc?

Comment: I thought of using imagemagick for the image-processing part, but am open to alternatives.

Comment: I don't like this question. There's too much I don't understand about what you need these for in the future. Are you never going to store them? That seems needlessly wasteful.

Comment: You haven't tried anything?.. Why don't you try and then post questions if you run into problems? (and include code when you do.)

Comment: I believe this question is just fine. He obviously has no idea where to start, and it is clear enough that he is looking for guidelines on how this may be achieved. +1

Comment: @jcolebrand: "I want to crop and _store_ the images in different sizes on Amazon S3." I just want to have the image, which I get from the vendor in only one (big) size, resized to the sizes needed for my views. I don't see how this is wasteful.

Comment: @Fosco: Tom is right, it's a general question I want to have clarified before I start writing code. I would prefer doing it with streams, if that's not possible I'll go the imagemagick way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get around saving the full-size image to disk temporarily, since resizing/cropping/etc would normally require having the full image file.  So, I say ImageMagick.

Comment: Nah, you could do it with streams, but that would either require a LOT of memory or would require a LOT of network traffic. Just not worth it imo tho.

Comment: You're right; I guess I meant you would need the full image to do the manipulation (whether it's on disk or in memory), so it would be silly to use a stream and in-memory buffer since disk space is cheaper than RAM.

Comment: The problem with saving to disk is, that it comes with an administrative overhead. I'm not even sure if the most of the hosted node.js services can handle it (that's not a problem for me, just to say).

Comment: @Thomas and the problem with constantly streaming as you manipulate is the intensive CPU and memory overhead. You're going to do this on a VPS yes? Do you pay by the CPU hour or by the "instance is currently live" hour? Paying by the CPU hour it makes a lot more sense to pay that cost once.

Comment: There is nothing in simple image resizing (even with resampling) that would absolutely require having random access to the whole image. From algorithmic standpoint, this can be done incrementally. For the case of a simplest resize, "nearest pixel" reduction, you're just dropping every n-th  pixel in the given line and every n-th line. Obviously, this requires no memory whatsoever and only two counters. Things get more complicated if you want to enlarge the image, or use any form of resampling/interpolation, but even then the maximum you need is to hold the last n lines (n = resample radius).

Comment: As to whether there exist any Node.JS libraries that resize image streams incrementally without loading the whole data set into memory/disk, I'm still looking for one. Maybe I'll write such a library someday.

Neither https://github.com/aheckmann/gm nor https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas (nor, for that matter, any others which are based on ImageMagick, GraphicsMagick or Cairo) seem to be able to process images on a stream processing basis because the underlying libraries seem to always assume full random access to image data.